# Overflow and flex: change the size of border-box by CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

During overflow, when set `display: flex;` by default (i.e.`flex-direction: row`;), the width of the border box is the whole `scrollWidth`; while the height of the border box is only the `clientHeight`. One may check the blue-border by the following example. If we change the `flex-direction` as `column`, the situation exchanges.

My question is: **by directly set CSS, is their anyway to make the height of the border box to the whole content (i.e. `scrollHeight`), while keep `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row`?**

I know we can use JavaScript to set it as `scrollHeight`, but I want to know can we do it with CSS. I already tried `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`,  they have no effect on the border box.

```css
#parent {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    }

#main {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    /*flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-shrink: 0;*/
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">    
    <span id="main"> <span>sdfsdfdfd </span>
        sdfdsfsdfdsafadsfasdfafdfsdfsdffsfsdfdsfdsf 
        sdfsdaf
         sdfdsfa
           dsfsdfsd dsf
        dfas sdfdsfa
        dsfsdfsd
        dsfsdfsd
        dfs
        sdfsf
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: align-items: flex-start; to flex container

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks. It really works. now it contains everything in both direction. Thanks.